# PORT Change in error case: HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, http

I am consuming API using HttpURLConnection in my android application and its running fine but if I get response code except then 200 ok (like 404, 500) my port is changing when I hit next request after error response code:
my code for android request is below and wireshark log as well:

```
try {
            url = new URL(path_url + apiMsg); //in the real code, there is an ip and a port

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");

}
```

Please refer wireshark log:

https://files.fm/u/w7umrwwk

So how to avoid PORT change in error scenario as well like in success 200 case, so that we continue to run on the same PORT.

Answer (score 0):

read about sun.net.http.errorstream.enableBuffering in HttpURLConnection source code.

By default when response code is >= 400 then the connection is closed.
It is a clean though not so efficient way of handling error streams.

Instead of setting obscure system properties to handle this, it would be better to move to a proper http client like apache.